# Convert List to Map in java 8 by appending values for a key if exists

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to convert a List to map. if the key exists i just want to combine two values and separate them by "," and assign it to the key. If the key doesn't exist, i just want to assign directly as a key value pair and i want to use streams for this purpose.

Example:

```
List<Object> listObject = {something1,something2,something3}
Map<String,String> listToMap = listObject.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(listObject::getKey,listObject::getValue))
```

The above will error out if there any duplicate keys. Any suggestions are helpful here.

Comment: you need to pass a merge function to handle duplicate keys

Comment: @Eran any example would be helpful please

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected

Comment: `listObject` is a `List`, and `List` doesn't have a `getKey()` nor a `getValue()` method, so `listObject::getKey` and `listObject::getValue` will **fail to compile**. The code snippet is a bad example.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `toMap` to handle duplicate keys, you must pass a merge function, which accepts two values and returns a single value.

In your case, the merge function should concatenate the two values:

```
List<Object> listObject = {something1,something2,something3}
Map<String,String> listToMap =    
    listObject.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(listObject::getKey,
                                        listObject::getValue,
                                        (v1,v2)->v1+","+v2));
```

If you wish to save the values of the same key in a `List`, instead of concatenating them into a single `String`, use `groupingBy`:

```
List<Object> listObject = {something1,something2,something3}
Map<String,List<String>> listToMap =    
    listObject.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(listObject::getKey,
                                             Collectors.mapping(listObject::getValue,
                                                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: how do we save the values as a list as updated in the question?

Comment: I mean instead of saving it as a , seperated string, how can i save them in a list? @Eran